# Logon Message Powershell Script Runs But Does Not Launch Prompt

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, group-policy

I'm trying to setup a login prompt according to https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/desktop-and-application-streaming/generate-logon-messages-for-security-and-compliance-in-amazon-windows-workspaces/ because the group policy interactive logon message setting is not supported by AWS WorkSpaces.

I've created my bat file which launches the PowerShell script and created a Group Policy Object which is linked to my user OU.

When I run `GPRESULT /H` , it shows that the script ran, however I do not see the prompt at login.

Something seems to be preventing the prompt from showing at user login.

Whenever I run the script manually, I see the login prompt, so I know the script is working.

Please advise as to what might be causing the script not to work when running it with group policy on login.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Startup scripts are run asynchronously, by default.Startup scripts that run asynchronously will not be visible.

Setting startup scripts to run synchronously may cause the boot process to run slowly.

Enable the Run Startup Scripts Visible Group Policy
https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.Scripts::Run_Startup_Script_Visible